# Why no route when I try to replace a standard rails link with an ajax one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec, hyperlink

---

Summary: when I try to use the js links I get:

#### No route matches [GET] "/verify_link"

---

This original erb link works:

### links view

```
app/views/links/index.html.haml

= link_to 'verify', verify_link_path(id: link.id, table_row: index),
  class: 'verify',  title: 'Verify this link', remote: true
```

### links controller

```
  def verify_link
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    if @link.valid_get?
      @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
    end 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end 
  end
```

### links verify js erb

```
# app/views/links/verify_link.js.erb 
<%- if @link.verified_date %>
  $("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").html('<span class="done">Verified</span>');
<%- else %>
  $("span#verify_link_<%=params['table_row']%>").html('<span class="undone">Unverified</span>');
<%- end %>
```

But when I try to switch to use js:

### links view:

```
%a{href: "#", :data => {verifying_link: 'yes', id: link.id, table_row: index}}
  verify via js
```

### links verifying link js:

```
# app/assets/javascripts/verifying_link.js.erb

$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    $("h1").text('CHECKING...');
    $.get("/verify_link/#{data-id}&table_row=#{date-table-row}");
    $("h1").text('LINKER');
  });
});
```

I am getting

```
Started GET "/verify_link/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-03 12:53:38 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/verify_link"):
```

My Controller has:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController

 ...
def verify_link
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  if @link.valid_get?
    @link.update_attribute(:verified_date, Time.now)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

end
```

### Link Model:

```
#app/models/link.rb

def verify_link
  if valid_get?
    verified_date = Time.now
  end
end
```

### Routes

```
      ladmin_login        /ladmin/login(.:format)                    ladmin#login
      ladmin_logout        /ladmin/logout(.:format)                   ladmin#logout
      ...
             search        /search(.:format)                          links#index
    advanced_search        /advanced_search(.:format)                 links#advanced_search
       groups_links GET    /links/groups(.:format)                    links#groups
              links GET    /links(.:format)                           links#index
                    POST   /links(.:format)                           links#create
           new_link GET    /links/new(.:format)                       links#new
          edit_link GET    /links/:id/edit(.:format)                  links#edit
               link GET    /links/:id(.:format)                       links#show
                    PUT    /links/:id(.:format)                       links#update
                    DELETE /links/:id(.:format)                       links#destroy
toggle_full_details        /toggle_full_details(.:format)             links#toggle_full_details
 toggle_row_shading        /toggle_row_shading(.:format)              links#toggle_row_shading
        verify_link GET    /verify_link/:id(.:format)                 links#verify_link
      unverify_link GET    /unverify_link/:id(.:format)               links#unverify_link
               root        /                                          links#index
```

Mg network tab is showing `a 404 Not Found for localhost:3000/verify_link/`

The `h1` tag does gets its content changed though (ends up as "LINKER", different color to original) after click so it is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your question the error you are getting is

```
a 404 Not Found for localhost:3000/verify_link/
```

So where are your data-id and date-table-row? If you look at your js function **you are not getting data attribute values** so you need to first get there values from your link. Try:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[data-verifying-link]='yes'").click(function(){
    $("h1").text('CHECKING...');
    var id= $(this).data("id");
    var row = $(this).data("tableRow");
    $.get("/verify_link/"+id+"&table_row="+row);
    $("h1").text('LINKER');
  });
});
```